# having problems uploading mySQL database using phpMyAdmin on local machine connected remotly

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am able to connect to my .sql databases on my servers remotely with no problems, I can query and truncate the tables fine.  I can NOT however, upload (via import) the database files.

I have set the following in my php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

I have also uploaded the php.ini file to my server

However, when I log into phpMyAdmin on the localhost and connect to the server database, when on the import tab, it says that the file size is limited to 8,192KiB

I'm lost as to what the problem may be.  The max database size I am trying to upload is just under 30M. I have also tried to use a `.htaccess` file with no success.

To me, it seems that the local `phpMyAdmin` is not looking at the correct `php.ini` file.  Is there a way to see where `phpMyAdmin` is looking on the local machine to find the php.ini file.  I have tried running `phpinfo()` but for some reason it doesn'w want to open on that computer.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to connect to my .sql databases on my servers remotely with no problems*

If you can connect remotely with no problems, then don't use phpmyadmin to do your restore. Use another remote tool that doesn't use php.

try go to `my.cnf in /etc/mysql`and where it says

`bind-address       = 127.0.0.1`

Change it to your server's IP address. Restart mySQL. That way you should be able to connect remotely using something like mySQL Workbench (on their website), and upload the .sql

I recommend changing it back afterwards to avoid other problems.

Also make sure you make a user who has access from anywhere (`%`) or at least your home IP (wherever you're trying to connect from), and with enough privileges to restore the database. (Although if you make a root user with access from %, you can sometimes not get in using phpMyAdmin anymore.)

Load the file to your server with `FTP/SSH` and use `SSH` to restore the database with `mysql commands`.

Comment: A better solution would be to not do this with phpMyAdmin OR remote access to the MySQL server. Instead, gzip the SQL file and upload it to the remote server. Then, connect to the remote server with SSH, decompress the archive, and import the SQL file. This will be more secure, because your MySQL server won't be exposed to remote access. And, it will be *faster*.